# How '+' and '&' works in CSS pseudo?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have following code

```
.check-tag__input:focus + & {
        outline: none;
        background-color: #bbb;
    }

    .check-tag__input:checked + & {
        background-color: #BADA55;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

What use of + and & in this?

Comment: Well, `&` pseudo-selector belongs to less, not CSS. However, & can be used to make a nested selector that only applies its rules when an ancestor of the outer selector has a class.

Comment: @FerranBuireu Thanks for answer, can you please tell me what is the purpose of & and + here?
https://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/25741myb/
(last classes) or can you point me to reference, i could not found any,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the `&` does not affect the CSS at all. As I said, it only applies the rules when an ancestor of the outer selector has a class, so you can remove it.

It is useful to make sure that you don't overwrite any default rule puting an element without class. With the ampersand you "force" the rule to be applied only in certain cases. [Maybe this helps you](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-29/less-css-secrets-of-the-ampersand/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty good explanation of `&` in LESS and what it does: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-29/less-css-secrets-of-the-ampersand/

The `+` is just pure CSS and means that this style is only applied to elements that come right after another. For example:

```
.myClass + .yourClass {
    color: red;
}
```

This would make any element with the class `.yourClass` text color red, **but only if** the element comes right after an element with the class `.myClass`:

```
<span class='myClass'>Lorem ipsum</span>
<span class='yourClass'>This text is red</span>
<span class='yourClass'>But this isn't</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Afetr searching and checking lots articles i’ve Found this solution,
https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/